# Module scope not working on internal package registry after switching from public

Tags: npm, gitlab, npm-package

I've been reading a lot of threads on npm, private and public registries, GitLab, etc. But I haven't found a solution or possible cause for my issue.

My company has an old module that was originally pushed and hosted to their own scoped space in the npmjs registry(I'll use `@origscope\our-custom-module` for example).

Since that time(a long time ago), we have moved to GitLab, and we are trying to publish the module to GL's package registry and have our apps pull it from there.  Publishing the module isn't the issue.

The issue I have is trying to pull it down.  I've followed the docs, created tokens, updated the .npmrc file accordingly, etc.  However, the app I'm trying to switch over keeps trying to pull the package from npmjs, not the GL registry.  I've removed the package-lock file, cleared caches, etc.

Here's the twist.  I republished the module to GL using a different scope (`@newcope\our-custom-module`), change the package.json and .npmrc with the new scope, NO OTHER CHANGES, and it pulls fine.  So, it seems like something is stuck trying to pull the module, under the `@origscope`, from the external npmjs regsitry.

Any ideas?  Thank